# How to fit regression equation

Tags: regression

I was given an assignment with the question in the below picture:
[image: The questions]

I already answered i) i.e The test for the heterogeneity of variance using Bartlett procedure. 
My question here is at ii) I was asked to fit the regression equation but I was not given the dependent variable. How can I go about this type of question?

Comment: Re "not given the dependent variable:" could you please explain what "response observations" means then?

Comment: I would suggest drawing this on a Cartesian x,y system with x as given in the headlines and y as values from the columns (15 points in total). You may, as well,  call the y axis "Response observation". Maybe this will help you see things in  a clearer manner.

Comment: What equation is used?

Comment: Please type your question as text, do not just post a 
photograph or screenshot (see [here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3176/)). 
When you retype the question, add the [tag:self-study] tag 
& read [its wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). 
Then tell us what you understand thus far, what you've 
tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to help 
you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you 
is grounds for closing.